# Add variable prefix to angular routing not working

Tags: angular, routes, provider, prefix

I added prefix using providers in my app-routing.module.ts. This prefix is a variable string value

app-routing.module.ts.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '404',
    component: NotFoundComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => PosClientModule,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {acl: 'pos:view'}
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ onSameUrlNavigation: "ignore" })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: `${version ? '/' + version : ''}/pos-clients` }]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

---

pos-client-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'open',
    component: OpeningComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'close',
    component: CloseComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'quotes',
    loadChildren: () => QuotesModule,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {acl: 'pos:view'},
  },
  {
    path: 'payment',
    loadChildren: () => PaymentModule,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {acl: 'pos:view'}
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: ListComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PosClientRoutingModule {
}
```

But when try redirect a quote path using `this.route.navigate(['quotes'])` the app doesn't recognize the url, I have this error

> "instrument.js:109 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'unstable/pos-clients/quotes'"

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Hlj.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'quotes',
        loadChildren: () => 
         import('path of the module example./quotes/quotes.module').then(m => m.QuotesModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: {acl: 'pos:view'},
      }
    ];
```

Comment: This solution is not working. I have now this error ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk vendors-node_modules_metises-cdk_fesm2015_metises-cdk-input-multiple_mjs-node_modules_metises-e8636f failed.

Comment: I think this article will help you with what you are looking for. https://medium.com/ngconf/how-to-nest-lazy-loaded-modules-2d73a7881be

Hard to determine without seeing more of your code and structure.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?